# Calcular precio con descuento en la segunda unidad

Tags: java

Estoy comenzando a aprender a programar en Java y estoy atascado en un ejercicio que estoy desarrollando.

En el ejercicio que tengo que desarrollar sería con el siguiente planteamiento:

- Solicitar el precio de un producto.
- Solicitar el número de unidades del producto.
- El número de unidades tiene que ser 1 o 2 como máximo.
- En el caso de que sean 2 unidades aplicar un descuento del 70% a la 2ª unidad.
- Finalmente mostrar el precio inicial y el precio final con el descuento.

Tengo planteado parte del código donde aún me faltan por desarrollar muchas cosas, como por ejemplo limitar el numero de unidades que solo sea 1 o 2, y también aplicar el 70% de descuento a la 2ª unidad. De momento solo muestro un string diciendo " que tiene un descuento del 70% en la 2ª Unidad " pero no sé como aplicar ese descuento.

Aún estoy en las primeras etapas y en el ejercicio no puedo aún no puedo usar condicionales como "if else" . Por tanto en el ejercicio solo puedo usar el operador condicional "? :" .

Edito: Finalmente creo que logré realizar el ejercicio, este es el resultado:
Les agradeceria que me corrigieran si ven algún error. Un saludo y gracias por todo.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    // Variables Precios y Unidades
    float precioProducto1;
    byte numeroUnidades;
    float resultadoUnidades;
    float subTotal;
    float total;
    String mensajeResultado;
            
    //Preguntamos precio del producto
    System.out.println("Indroduce precio del producto: ");
    
    // Importamos el Metodo Scanner para introducir precio via teclado
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    // Asignamos el precio introducido a la variable precioProducto1
    precioProducto1 = scanner.nextFloat();
    
    //Preguntamos numero de unidades del producto
    System.out.println("Indroduce numero unidades del producto: ");
    
    // Asignamos el numero de unidades a la variable numeroUnidades
    numeroUnidades = scanner.nextByte();
    
    // Si el numero de unidades es 2 calculamos el 70% de descuento al precio del producto y si no será 0
    // asignamos el resultado a la variable subtotal
    subTotal = (numeroUnidades == 2 ? ((precioProducto1 * 30)/100) : 0);
    
    // La variable total sera la suma del precio del producto y el subtotal
    total = precioProducto1 + subTotal;
    
    // Variable para informar al cliente si tiene descuento o no  
    mensajeResultado = (numeroUnidades % 2 == 0) ? "¡Enhorabuena! Tienes un descuento del 70% en la 2ª Unidad. " : "Lo siento. No tienes descuento.";

    // Mostramos finalmente el resultado del descuento si lo hubiera y el total 
    System.out.println(mensajeResultado + " Precio 2ª Unidad: " + subTotal + "€" + ". Precio Total: " + total + "€");

}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Está bien raro que te hayan enseñado el operador ternario `?` y no las sentencias `if` y `else`. En fin, probablemente tampoco te dejen usar aún un bucle `while` que es lo que se suele usar para validar datos, en este caso el número de unidades (1 o 2), entonces no sabría ayudarte en esa parte.

En lo que sí puedo ayudar es en aplicar el descuento al precio, yo modificaría lo siguiente, así:

```java
    // Preguntamos numero de unidades del producto
    System.out.println("Indroduce numero unidades del producto: ");
    
    numeroUnidades = scanner.nextByte();
    // Preguntamos numero de unidades del producto
        System.out.println("Indroduce numero unidades del producto: ");
     
    numeroUnidades = scanner.nextByte();
    // Tiene o no tiene descuento en funcion si es 1 o 2 unidades;
    boolean descuento = (numeroUnidades == 2);
    float precioTotal = precioProducto1;
    // Si el descuento está activo, hay 2 productos, pero el precio del segundo va con el 70%, sino, no se suma nada.
    precioTotal += (descuento ? (precioProducto1 * 0.3) : 0);
    System.out.println(
        "El total es: " +
        precioTotal +
        (descuento ? " Tiene descuento del 70% en la 2ª Unidad " : " No tiene descuento ")
    );
```

Comment: Ante todo gracias por contestar. He probado el código que me has dado pero me dá error. Y no sé muy bien a que se debe pero creo que el problema es que la variable "descuento = (numeroUnidades == 2);" la tengo declarada como tipo "boolean" y creo que no puedo declararla como "float" o "int"  o de otro tipo por que el operador relacional "==" solo da como resultado un "boolean"

Comment: Tienes razón, acabo de editar mi respuesta.

Comment: Y solo como comentario extra, ya que vi que conseguiste solucionarlo también por cuenta propia. Una vez aprendas a usar if y else, en este caso es mejor usar esas instrucciones. El operador ternario lo utilizas para hacer una asignación de manera rápida del tipo: valor == condicion ? A : B

Comment: Carlos Córdova, muchas gracias por intentar ayudar, muy agradecido de verdad.